# Hide/disable webform values on select list if a value has been chosen once

Tags: webforms, entities

I would like to create a webform with a select list/radios where each option on the list can be chosen only once (unique). I can of course check "Unique" in Validation settings but this is not an optimal solution because users have to "guess" what values are still accessible.

Is there a possibility to create a webform field where:

- the field is required (select list/radios),
- each value can be checked only once (unique),
- **checked/chosen values are hidden/disabled if they have been used once** by other users.

Comment: I've found the answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/158531/21269